# Displaying error when link to website on facebook posts

Tags: facebook, dns, cloudflare, bad-gateway

I use cloudflare on my website and when I try to post on facebook a link to this site it display error:

> mydomain.com | 502: Bad gateway
>   CloudFlare Ray ID: 31fa674e77c32462 • Your IP: 2a03:2880:XXXX:XXe5:face:b00c:0:8000 • Performance & security by CloudFlare

Preview on screen: 
[image]

I want to show any data from my website instead of error when link on FB, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what happens is that Facebook fetches the data from the server and then displays it to you. For whatever reason, Facebook gets the error and you don't.

Not sure if this is applicable to you, but I found a help page explaining how to troubleshoot a similar situation.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217720788-Why-doesn-t-my-site-display-correctly-when-sharing-to-Facebook-

Either you put it in the "Under Attack" mode, which probably uses very aggressive secret rules, or you made some kind of a firewall rule blocking Facebook's IPs. So you will need to locate anything like that and undo it.

You can also do a quick workaround by whitelisting "AS32934" in your IP firewall. If this solves the issue, do look in the aforementioned settings for the actual cause and remove the override if you're feeling paranoid enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I just fixed this problem by disabling IP V6 and by setting security level as Essentially Off on my Cloudflare dashboard.